# ASP.NET MVC3: Split into two different Tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Form -> Submit

Takes you to view of the new entry.

How can I open a new tab that sends you to a new actionresult `return File(document, mimeType);` while still directing you on the main tab?

I'm at a loss, I cant open a new tab via ASP.NET Code, nor invoke two different actionresults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do it client side. You have 2 options:

**1) A shell page that has nothing except for the following javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.open("@Model.DownloadUrl", "");
    window.location.href = "@Model.RedirectUrl";
});
```

**2) Modifying the view to check for a `DownloadUrl` via javascript and download it if available:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (@!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DownloadUrl)) {
        window.open("@Model.DownloadUrl", "");
    }
});
```

In either case, there's no way to *force* the new window to be opened as a new tab. That's a user's browser setting. The javascript above opens a new tab in the version of Chrome and Firefox I have but not in IE.

Comment: Window.Open is causing a new window, not tab. :/

Comment: I've updated my answer. The gist is you can't force the user to open a new tab, but the new code above will open a new tab in some versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem should be solved on the client side, not only on the server. Maybe I misunderstood something, but if you want to open a new *browser* tab, you just need to place a `<a href="@Html.Action("SomeAction")" target="_blank">` (Razor syntax) in your main tab.